# Problems in reinforcement learning: bug, parameters tuning, and training period

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am currently training a reinforcement learning agent using a simple Neural Network with 100 hidden elements to solve 2048 game. I am using DQN's reinforcement learning algorithm (i.e. Q-learning with replay memory), but with 2 layers Neural Network instead of Deep Neural Network.

However, I left it trained on my laptop overnight (~7 hours, ~1000 games played, > 100000 steps) and the score does not seem to increase. I suspect there might be 3 sources of errors in my code: bug, parameters tuned badly, or maybe I just don't wait long enough.

Is there any method to figure out what is wrong with the code?
And what is the best practice to improve the training results?

Answer (score 0):

I'll talk about all three of your hypothesis.

1. If you are using a standard DL framework like caffe or tensorflow, the chance of it being a bug is small.
2. Try decreasing the learning rate. Maybe you set it too high for the network to converge.
3. The training time of 100000 steps is not that long. For a simple [pong game](https://github.com/asrivat1/DeepLearningVideoGames/), you need to train around 500000 steps to get a good accuracy. So you can try training it for longer.

Also, 2048 is a fairly complicated game, so maybe you network is not deep enough to learn how to play it. Two layers is not much for such a complicated game. Try increasing the number of hidden layers. Perhaps you can use the network provided [here](https://github.com/asrivat1/DeepLearningVideoGames/)

Comment: The learning rate might also be too small. You can find out whether to increase or decrease by looking at the training progress. If the loss values are violently fluctuating your learning rate is too large. If there is simply no visible progress it's more likely too small.